# Background Tasks for regular file syncing

Tags: c#, xaml, backgroundworker, windows-phone-8.1

For my app I need to be able to let the user specify a given time and let my app run a background task at that specific time.

I understand that with wp8.1 a timetrigger background task can only run every 15 minutes. Is there anything I can do to ensure my app will run the task if the time has gone 10 minutes over the user's specified time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what I understand tasks are only executed in intervals multiple of 15 minutes in Windows 8.1 and 30 minutes in Windows Phone 8.1. Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh977059.aspx

Comment: Even worse for me then! How does android and iOS manage this if MS has put a restriction on it all.

Comment: I think this behavior is still a huge flaw on Windows Phone... I can understand the battery issue but still it is really painful.

Answer (score 0):

I can not add a comment, that's why I share my experiences as an answer.

We had a similar problem in an application - we target the Windows Store 8.1 platform but our experiences can be relevant for you as the app cycles in the two platform are converged (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn632424.aspx).

In our app we have to monitor streams and collect information. This logic has to be executed per minute what is not supported, as mentioned. That's why we use a simple Task with a CancellationTokenSource, and we start/stop the task in the app cycle-related events (Suspending, Resuming). This "solution" is not acceptable if the execution of the background logic is required when the app is suspended, too, but in our case this was not required.